# Removing background on drawable used in floating action button when clicked (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, user-interface, frontend, floating-action-button

I am using a Github library (https://github.com/oguzbilgener/CircularFloatingActionMenu) to create a circular floating action menu programmatically. Using drawables I have added a menu and an exit icon to the floating action menu and I want to remove the square border around the menu and exit icons that appear when the menu is clicked. I have tried things like programmatically setting the background of the button to be null or changing it's 'alpha' value, neither of which has the desired effect.

[image: menu icon][image: exit icon]

There are other questions posted asking this but they are all creating the menu/button using XML while I'm doing it programmatically using Java. Is there any way to remove the border (and if possible fill the whole menu button with the icons rather than have it enclosed inside)? Below I have inserted the code I'm using from the library for convenience:

```
        // Create our Floating Action Button
        final ImageView fabIconNew = new ImageView(getActivity());
        /*  Set the icon in the center of the Floating Action Button
            Old Deprecated way to get drawable -> getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_new_light)
            Instead, use -> getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_action_new_light)
         */
        fabIconNew.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.menu_icon));

        final FloatingActionButton rightLowerButton = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(getActivity())
                .setContentView(fabIconNew)
                .setPosition(FloatingActionButton.POSITION_BOTTOM_RIGHT)
                .build();

        // Create your menu items which are also Floating Action Buttons
        SubActionButton.Builder rLSubBuilder = new SubActionButton.Builder(getActivity());
        // Create an image view for each menu item
        ImageView menuOption1 = new ImageView(getActivity());
        ImageView menuOption2 = new ImageView(getActivity());

        // Set the ico/*rea*/n for each menu item
        menuOption1.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.button_sub_action));
        menuOption2.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.button_sub_action_selector));

        // Build the menu with default options: 90 degrees, 72dp radius.
        // Set 4 default SubActionButtons
        final FloatingActionMenu rightLowerMenu = new FloatingActionMenu.Builder(getActivity())
                .addSubActionView(rLSubBuilder.setContentView(menuOption1).build())
                .addSubActionView(rLSubBuilder.setContentView(menuOption2).build())
                .attachTo(rightLowerButton)
                //.setStartAngle(360)
                .build();

        // Listen for menu open and close events to animate the button content view
        rightLowerMenu.setStateChangeListener(new FloatingActionMenu.MenuStateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMenuOpened(FloatingActionMenu menu) {
                // Rotate the icon of rightLowerButton 45 degrees clockwise
//                fabIconNew.setRotation(0);
                fabIconNew.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.exit_icon));
                PropertyValuesHolder pvhR = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.ROTATION, 0);
                ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(fabIconNew, pvhR);
                animation.start();
            }

            @Override
            public void onMenuClosed(FloatingActionMenu menu) {
                // Rotate the icon of rightLowerButton 45 degrees counter-clockwise
//                fabIconNew.setRotation(45);
                fabIconNew.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.menu_icon));
                PropertyValuesHolder pvhR = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.ROTATION, 0);
                ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(fabIconNew, pvhR);
                animation.start();
            }
        });

        // OnClickListeners for each menu item
        menuOption1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Option 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                /*
                    Could also go to an Intent or perform whatever action you want.
                    To go to another Activity, you would use something like:
                    Intent goToActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Name_Of_Activity.class)
                    startActivity(goToActivity);
                 */
            }
        });

        menuOption2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Option 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                NavHostFragment.findNavController(FirstFragment.this)
                        .navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment);
                rightLowerMenu.close(true);
                rightLowerButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });
```

Comment: exit_icon, menu_icon are they png images?

Comment: @SarathSiva yes they are

Comment: https://blog.mindorks.com/using-svg-vector-drawables-in-android